# Why is Apple using the settings icon for showing more options?

Tags: icons, settings, options, mac-os-x

What could be the reason for Apple to use a gear-wheel in its Finder to show more options when everybody else seems to use this icon for "Settings"? Even Apple uses it again for the System Preferences. Is there a concept I don't see here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apple uses the gear for 'Actions'. For preferences Apple uses an image of several gears (instead of just one).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still wonder why it has to be the gear for 'Actions' while the rest of the world seems to use this for settings: http://thenounproject.com/search/?q=settings

Comment: I think that's confusing too, although I can't think of a better one. Picking icons can be very arbitrary if you ask me.